# Wait for certain timestamp in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sleep

I have a MAIN SSIS package that calls 2 child packages internally.

This MAIN pkg fires 2 packages together (Using Execute process tasks "dtexec /DTS") and there is a business rule to look at a table column for a certain timestamp and wait until that timestamp is todays date (this timestamp is updated by third party).

I am currently using a foreach loop to check this timestamp, however I am using a T-SQL statement to sleep for 10 mins between each retry i.e. :

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:10:00'
```

My question is that will this wait HANG the entire MAIN SSIS pkg or just this child pkg?

Also if there is a better wayt o achieve this functionality so that both the child pkgs can run in parallel without hanging each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it hang the entire main SSIS package? If your main package has a precedent on this step then yes the whole package will wait. You may wish to consider calling the main package from a SQL Agent job with a recurring 10 minutes shcedule.

But the trigger idea is even better.

Comment: To examine my concern better,  when I say will the Main pkg wait I meant that if child pkg 2 is doing some processing in parallel to this package which is in Wait state,  will my child pckg 2 also hang or will that continue to process? There is no relation between these 2 child pkgs,  the only relation is a success email at the end once both child pkgs are done.

Comment: No it won't wait, it will run in parallel. But why don't you test it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:
Regarding the package design:
Put both of your child packages inside a sequence container on the control surface of the parent package. Do not "connect" them together, so that they run in parallel. Place an execute sql task outside the sequence container. This task will check for the time stamp updated by the third party. Use a condition to decide whether or not the sequence container be executed.

How do you plan to schedule your parent package?
Create a sql job to run the package. 
Can we create a trigger on the table that would call the job, if the date is correct. A relevant link: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=270744

This is an interesting problem. Please post your findings and solution description. Good luck!